# Can't restore VM in Python Virtualbox API

Tags: python, virtualbox, pywin32

I want to restore a VM in Virtualbox API but I got this exception:

```
AttributeError: '<win32com.gen_py.VirtualBox Type Library.IConsole instance at 0x41746480>' object has no attribute 'restoreSnapshot'
```

How can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
import vboxapi

def wait(sth):
    sth.waitForCompletion(-1)

class Foo:
    mgr=vboxapi.VirtualBoxManager()
    vbox=mgr.vbox
    vm=vbox.findMachine(const.VM_NAME)

    def __init__(self):
        self.session=self.mgr.getSessionObject(self.vbox)
        wait(self.vm.launchVMProcess(self.session, 'gui', ''))

    def restore(self):
        console=self.session.console
        wait(console.powerDown())
        wait(console.restoreSnapshot(self.vm.findSnapshot('test')))
        wait(console.powerUp())

foo=Foo()
foo.restore()
```

I'm using vboxapi 5.0.10 under Python 3.4.

Plus, when I changed `console.restoreSnapshot` to `self.vm.restoreSnapshot` according to the VirtualBox SDK Ref, it says that `Method Machine::restoreSnapshot is not implemented`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's my solution after days of trying.

```
def restore(self):
    self.log('=== powering down')
    wait(self.session.console.powerDown())
    self.session.unlockMachine()

    self.log('=== restoring')
    self.session=self.mgr.openMachineSession(self.vm) # WHY?
    self.vm=self.session.machine
    wait(self.vm.restoreSnapshot(self.vm.findSnapshot(const.VM_BASE_SNAPSHOT)))
    self.session.unlockMachine()

    self.log('=== powering up')
    self.vm=self.vbox.findMachine(const.VM_NAME)
    self.session=self.mgr.getSessionObject(self.vbox)
    while True:
        try:
            wait(self.vm.launchVMProcess(self.session,'gui' if const.DEBUG else 'headless',''))
        except pywintypes.com_error: #unlocking machine
            time.sleep(.1)
        else:
            break
```

Although I don't know the reason, it works anyway.